# js скрипт на клик определённой кнопки на сайте

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, click

Помогите написать небольшой скрипт.

Необоходимо написать скрипт на множественное нажатие определённой кнопки на сайте.

Чтобы нажатие происходило определённое количество раз за определённый промежуток времени, а в конце показывался alert с текстовым сообщением("Операция успешна" или "Не удалось")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам банальный пример того, что вы хотите. Просто и понятно. В переменной `count` - количество нажатий. На кнопку навешен обработчик на клик - `processingAction`. Внутри всегда делаем инкремент количесва нажатий, а затем проверяем, сколько раз нажали, если первое нажатие - сохраняем первый интервал в секундах, а когда пятое нажатие - сохраняем последний интервал в секундах. Вычисляем количество секунд, пройденных с момента первого и последнего нажатия и выводим сообщение, если условие выполнено за большее или меньшее количество секунд.

```js
var count = 0;
var lastInterval, firstInterval;

function processingAction() {
  count++;
  if (count === 1) {
    firstInterval = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  }
  if (count === 5) {
    lastInterval = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    console.log(lastInterval - firstInterval);
    if (lastInterval - firstInterval > 5) {
      alert('Pressed five times! (more 5 sec)');
    } else {
      alert('Pressed five times! (less 5 sec)');
    }
    
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="processingAction()"> Push me! </button>
```

Из этого примера скажу отдно: глобальные переменные - зло. Ну это так, для общего развития. И вообще, следует показать свои наработки в вопросе и пояснять, что не получилось, тут у нас так принято.

Comment: Объясните такой странный выбор условия, почему `if (count >= 5) {` недостаточно?

Comment: @VasiliyRusin да это просто набросал быстренько, а так  - вы правы, можно короче